# How to remove these black areas of Bake?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Is there any way to hide these areas at the time of Bake?

[image]

Comment: Black appears where geometry intersects/overlap. I am wondering, will Mask modifier or Boolean subtract will do the job while baking?

Comment: I understand how it works, but is not there a way to hide or remove this area during the bake? I do not know how to use these modifiers.